# Rails Reload ActionView::Template while server running in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I want to reload an ActionView::Template while the server is running in production mode.

Let's assume the server is running in production mode and i could NOT restart/reload the server in any way. And the layout.html.erb gets changed.
How can i relaod the template, so the changes can take affect.

Answer (score 2):

### Found a working solution.

Rails caches Templates with the `ActionView::Resolver::Cache`. If you get the resolver you can then clear the context with `clear_cache`.

In an `ApplicationController` you recieve the context via `lookup_context.view_paths.paths.first`. Just call `clear_cache` on the resolver and Rails will reload the cache at the next request.

Comment: Don't know why your question was downvoted, I was looking for just that. Your solution wasn't working for Rail4 and 5 (or I just misunderstand you). I'm doing this: `TheController.view_paths.paths.map(&:clear_cache)`. I'm using it in console and when testing the app with production env (to get it faster on Windows).